# React - How to print the value of an input onChange inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my component:

```
export default function ImageUpload({ onSuccess, children}) {

  let value = '';
  const onUpload = async (element) => {
    element = element.target.files;
    let response;
    // Call endpoint to upload the file 
    value = element[0].name;
    return onSuccess(response.url);   
  };

  return <div>
    <div >
      {children}
      <input type="file" id="upload" onChange={onUpload.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <span>{value}</span>
  </div>; 
}
```

I would like to print inside the span the name of the file chosen from the user.
I use redux for the state, but this information is not something that belongs to the state.
This way does not work, could someone explain me why?

*UPDATE*
Since looks like there is no way to achieve this without state my question is about the best approach:
Use Redux also if I don't need this value outside the component or use the internal state of the component but ending to have both Redux and this state?

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't belong into the state? The component has to be re-rendered to show the name of the file. You could put at least the name(s) of the file(s) in the state.

Comment: Because is an information that are useful only inside the component, and never used outside.

Answer (score 2):

I can think about changing the approach, and transform your component to a class type component, something like that:

```
export default class ImageUpload extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
    this.onUpload = this.onUpload.bind(this)
  }

  onUpload() {
    let value = '';
    const onUpload = async (element) => {
      element = element.target.files;
      let response;
      // Call endpoint to upload the file 
      value = element[0].name;
      this.props.onSuccess(response.url);
      this.setState({ value: value })
    };
  }

  render () {
    return <div>
      <div >
        {children}
        <input type="file" id="upload" onChange={this.onUpload} />
      </div>
      <span>{this.state.value}</span>
    </div>;
  }

}
```

Comment: onUpload bind in render in unnecessary if you bind it in constructor.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this without using the internal state of the component